# Setting column flow from R to L with Hebrew text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am setting up a document with one page english, the next translated in Hebrew. It's a 2 column layout, and I need to get the text on the hebrew page to first fill the R column and then the L column.
I know I could set up some workaround, but I'd love to learn how to do this the right way.
How can I do that? (I do not have the middle-eastern edition.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The canonically-correct way per Adobe is to choose the **World-Ready Paragraph Composer**, which will flow that text in the chosen text-frame Right to left - then you thread that right hand text frame to a new column to its left...

It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, in InDesign CC, the given frame to which this is applied indicates it on-layout with a highlight to the right-hand side of each affected line - so in this screengrab, I've applied it to two adjacent text-frames.
[image]

Note that although I left the "lorem ipsum" filler in there, I did also tell InDesign in the "language" selection area that these areas were Hebrew; for myself I'd set specific character and paragraph styles for Hebrew, as well as carefully choosing World-Ready Paragraph Composer for each relevant frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the text set as hebrew, and Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer is checked as well. However, the column flow is still from Left to Right. (The world-ready paragraph composer makes the letters show up in proper order, instead of backwards. The column flow, though is still filling in the L and then the R.)

Comment: column flow is just threading - you can thread from any text frame to any other - left, right, up, down, next spread - you choose!

Comment: I still don't get it- when I insert text, it automatically fills the L and then the R. How can I switch that? I really appreciate your helping me with this!

Comment: Aaah- I hear what you're saying. I guess the problem is that I have the document set up with columns- one text box w/ columns, so I can't easily change the threading. This is imp so I can align to base grid (can I do this otherwise?)

Comment: You can retread existing text framed at any time. Look it up in ID docs!

Comment: I understand that, but if it's all in one text frame- that is the situation I am referring to. I think I will have to just split the columns into 2 separate text boxes, then the rethreading can work.

Comment: Yup - that's where I'd go with it.

Comment: But then is there a way to align to baseline grid?

Comment: Per paragraph baseline grid still seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

i found the way!
windows--type & table--story
and you will find that very small icon hiding :)
enjoy!
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t think this would work for the asker here, since this setting is specific to the Middle Eastern version of InDesign, which the asker does not have.